# Child Div is not stretching to fit the contents of the browser window vertically.

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a google map canvas on it. It has a header, a footer, and a side panel on each side, a container div and a map canvas div.

The container div contains the side panels and the map-canvas div. My problem is that I cannot get the container div and all divs it contains to stretch to the contents of the browser window vertically.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header"></header>
            <div id="container" >
                <div id="panel"></div>
                <div id="panel2"></div>
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
        <footer id="footer"></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{ height: 100% auto;min-height:500px; width:100% auto;z-index:2;overflow:auto;}
#map-canvas { width:100% auto; height: 100% auto; min-height:500px; margin: 0px; z-index:3;padding: 0px; font-family: NotoSans, Helvetica, Arial; }
#panel   { background-color: #F0F0F0 ; height:100% auto;width:200px; z-index:3;min-height:500px; float:left; }
#panel2  { background-color: #F0F0F0 ; height:100% auto;width:200px; z-index:3;min-height:500px; float:right; }
#header { background-color: #F0F0F0 ; width:100%; min-width:1000px; z-index:3;height:100px;}
#footer { background-color: #F0F0F0 ; width:100%; z-index:4;min-width:1000px;height:100px;}
html, body{ height:100%;width:100%; margin: 0px; z-index:2;padding: 10px; font-family: NotoSans, Helvetica, Arial; }
```

Comment: Do you want the page not to scroll at all?

Comment: Yes. Because this is just a template that I am using on other pages where the contained div might be filled in a way that fills over the boundaries of the browser window

Comment: ok then, the answer I gave you should behave correctly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but this should work quite well, I think.

But be sure you also set media queries for [width](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width) and [height](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#height) to keep the page responsive when visited on smaller screen (eg. phone).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <style>
        #wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        }
        #header, #footer {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
        }
        #header {top: 0;}
        #footer {bottom: 0;}
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            bottom: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #panel, #panel2 {
            background-color: #CCC;
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 500px;
            float: left;
       }
       #panel2 {
            float: right;
       }
       #map-canvas {
            min-height: 500px;
            overflow: auto;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="header"></header>
        <div id="container" >
            <div id="panel"></div>
            <div id="panel2"></div>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <footer id="footer"></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```